# Source build vs Binary build?

Tags: eclipse, ant, building

Eclipse has a visual properties file tool for graphically composing you ant **build.properties** files.  It makes reference to so-called "binary builds" as well as "source builds".  The term *source* build makes sense: you're compiling sources.

"Binary builds" is throwing me off - is that referring to library (JAR) linking??

Answer (score -4, accepted):

OK this one was a douzy - apparently Eclipse allows you to reverse compile your CLASS files back to Java files; this is also known as a "binary build" - you're literally building the bytecode back into source.

Answer (score 6):

- Binary build : The compiled sources and files which will be packaged in the plug-in.
- Source build : Selected sources and files which will be packaged without compilation.

also see [Feature Manifest Editor](https://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Fguide%2Ftools%2Feditors%2Ffeature_editor%2Ffeature_editor.htm)

Comment: And the reason to build a `sources-jar file is, that you can easily [attach the sources](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-properties-source-attachment.htm) to the jar file, so that it is easier to debug: then you can jump to the real source code, including all comments. If you don't attach the sources, then Eclipse will just decompile the java-class files to make them readable.